# Image are not rendered for the guest user

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, guest-user

Don't know why my uploaded image not rendered for the guest user

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314288&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: No i check they are alreay check

Comment: where is the image being stored?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the object permission on the Electronic Media Group object, just give read access to it.